# Remove project parameter override via stored procedure

Tags: parameters, configuration, ssis

I know I can use catalog.set_object_parameter to assign a value to a project or package parameter.  My issue, though, is there have been some overrides set on some parameters that I would like removed so the packages in question will use the value set on the project.params file.

Other than going into the Configurate window and modifying the value, is there another option that can be scripted?  Our DBA's prefer to execute scripts provided by users to minimize potential errors.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's the [catalog.clear_object_parameter_value](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878144.aspx) method.

This script will clear the value assigned to my parameter `ConfigureParameter` which exists in package `Package.dtsx`, in Folder `POC` and is in the project `SSISConfigMixAndMatch`. The value of 30 for the object indicates this is for a package, 20 indicates it's a project level parameter.

```
EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[clear_object_parameter_value]
    @object_type = 30
,   @object_name = N'Package.dtsx'
,   @parameter_name = N'ConfigureParameter'
,   @folder_name = N'POC'
,   @project_name = N'SSISConfigMixAndMatch'
```

Comment: Thanks muchly, sorry, should have seen that